# Relation between the Poincare polynomial and its homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, homological-algebra

I am struggling with the following problem.

---

Let $k$ be a field and $C_q$ a finite collection of finite-dimensional vector-spaces that form a chain complex:
$$
\cdots\xrightarrow[]{\alpha_{k+2}} C_{k+1}\xrightarrow[]{\alpha_{k+1}} C_k \xrightarrow[]{\alpha_{k}} C_{k-1}\xrightarrow[]{\alpha_{k-1}} \cdots
$$
Define the Poincare polynomial of the (graded vector space) $C_*=\oplus_{q\geq 0}C_q$
$$
\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T)=\sum_{q\geq 0}(\dim C_q)\cdot T^q
$$
If $H_*=H_*(C)$ is the graded $k$-vector space of homology of $C_*$, then the corresponding Poincare polynomial satisfy:
$$
\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T)\succ \mathcal{P}_{H_*}(T)
$$
Conclude the Euler-Poincare Theorem:
$$
\sum_{q\geq 0}(-1)^q(\dim C_q)=\sum_{q\geq 0}(-1)^q(\dim H_q(C))
$$
Hint: Use the following corollary

> Let $\varphi:V\rightarrow U$ be a linear transformation of vector
>   spaces over a field $F$. Then $\ker\varphi$ is a subspace of $V$,
>   $\varphi(V)$ is a subspace of $U$, and $\dim V= \dim \ker\varphi
>  +\dim\varphi(V)$.

---

I have already shown that $p(x)\succ q(x)$ is a partial order on a field iff $\frac{p(x)-q(x)}{1+x}$ is a polynomial with nonnegative coefficients so I don't need to do that part. I am struggling specifically with showing $\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T)\succ\mathcal{P}_{H_*}(T)$. I know this well established relation by [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Poincar%C3%A9_series), but I am stuggling to prove it myself. I am new to working with homologies. Below is my attempt.

---

Assume the hypothesis. First we want to show that $\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T)\succ \mathcal{P}_{H_*}(T)$. Consider 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T) - \mathcal{P}_{H_*}(T)}{1+T} &=& \frac{\sum_{q\geq 0}(\dim C_q)\cdot T^q - \sum_{q\geq 0}(\dim H_q(C))\cdot T^q}{1+T}\\
&=&\frac{\sum_{q\geq 0}(\dim C_q-\dim H_q(C))\cdot T^q}{1+T}
\end{eqnarray*}
By the corollary, we know
\begin{eqnarray}
\dim(C_q)&=& \dim(\ker(\alpha_{q}))+\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_q))
\end{eqnarray}
By definition, $H_q(C) =\ker(\alpha_q)/\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1})$. Then
$$
\dim(H_q(C))=\dim(\ker(\alpha_q))-\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1})).
$$
Consider 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\dim(C_q)- \dim(H_q(C))&=& \dim(\ker(\alpha_{q}))+\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_q))-[\dim(\ker(\alpha_q))-\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1}))]\\
&=& \dim(\ker(\alpha_{q}))+\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_q))-\dim(\ker(\alpha_q))+\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1}))\\
&=& \dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_q))+ \dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1}))
\end{eqnarray*}
Because $\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_q))+ \dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1}))\geq 0$, we have $\dim(C_q)- \dim(H_q(C))\geq 0$. Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
Q(T)&=& \sum_{q\geq 0}(\dim C_q-\dim H_q(C))\cdot T^q.
\end{eqnarray*}
Notice $Q(T)$ has nonnegative coefficients. Therefore $Q(T)\succ 0$. This means
$$
\frac{Q(T)}{1+T}
$$
is a polynomial will nonnegative cofficients. Recall
$$
\frac{Q(T)}{1+T} = \frac{\sum_{q\geq 0}(\dim C_q-\dim H_q(C))\cdot T^q}{1+T} = \frac{\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T) - \mathcal{P}_{H_*}(T)}{1+T}
$$
Hence $\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T)\succ \mathcal{P}_{H_*}(T)$.

---

Any advice or help would be much appreciated. I am not sure if what I have so far is right. Thanks.

---

Here are some additional things I know.

1. $\alpha_{k+1}\circ \alpha_k =0$.
2. Im$(\alpha_{k+1})\subseteq \ker \alpha_k$

Comment: Have you tried to expand $\dim C_q$ and $\dim\big(H_q(C)\big)$ as $\dim(C_q) =  \dim\big(\ker(\alpha_{q-1})\big)+\dim\big(\text{Im}(\alpha_q)\big)$ and $\dim\big(H_q(C)\big)=\dim(\ker \alpha_q)-\dim(\textrm{Im}\alpha_{q+1})$ , and thereafter to use the fact that $C_*$ is a chain complex?

Comment: I have tried expanding both $\dim(C_q$) and $\dim(H_q(C))$. So I understand those results. I'll be honest though. I don't see the connection with the chain complex immediately. I am reviewing the definition now.

Comment: From the corollary, I think you get $\dim(C_q) =  \dim\big(\ker(\alpha_{q })\big)+\dim\big(\text{Im}(\alpha_q)\big)$ ?

Comment: Oh my goodness, you are right. That was my bad. I made the revision above and added everything I have so far.

Comment: Isn't $\mathcal{P}_{C_*}(T)\succ\mathcal{P}_{H_*}(T)$ done yet? We have that $\dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_q))+ \dim(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1}))$ is non-negative, so take $Q(t)=\sum_{q\geq0} \Big(\dim\big(\text{Im}(\alpha_q)\big)+ \dim\big(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1})\big)\Big)\cdot T^q$

Comment: I believe I got it. I posted my solution above.

Comment: Good! How do you conclude from here?

Comment: I should set $T=-1$ right? But I am running into an issue with the denominator now.

Comment: I'm not sure, I just noticed that $Q(-1)=\sum_{q\geq0} \Big(\dim\big(\text{Im}(\alpha_q)\big)+ \dim\big(\text{Im}(\alpha_{q+1})\big)\Big)\cdot (-1)^q=\cdots= \dim \mathrm{Im}\alpha_0$. Also, who is $\mathrm{Im}\alpha_0$?. From the above it is almost done

Comment: How do you get $\dim (\text{Im}\alpha_0)$?

Comment: Also the Im$(\alpha_0)=0$. So it has no dimension. Making $\sum_{q\geq 0}(\dim C_q-\dim H_q(C))(-1)^q = \sum_{q\geq 0}(-1)^q\dim C_q-\sum_{q\geq 0}(-1)^q\dim H_q(C)) =0$. Therefore $\sum_{q\geq 0}(-1)^q(\dim C_q)=\sum_{q\geq 0}(-1)^q(\dim H_q(C))$.